# Test not work without parentheses in VUEJS 2

Tags: vuejs2

I make testing to VueJS 2 application using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/).

I need to test if a method was called when clicking in my button, the problem is, when I put my method in `click` without paratheses, he is not called in my test.

**ButtonAnchor.vue**

```
<template>
 <div>
  <a v-on:click="triggerAnchor">{{ text }}</a>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  [...]
  methods: {
   triggerAnchor(event) { ... }
  },
</script>
```

**BaseAnchor.spec.js**

```
import { mount } from 'vue-test-utils';
import BaseAnchor from '@/components/BaseAnchor';

[...]

it('should called `triggerAnchor` when clicked button', () => {
  const vm = mount(BaseAnchor).vm;
  const buttonLink = vm.$el.querySelector('a');
  const spy = jest.spyOn(vm, 'triggerAnchor');

  buttonLink.click();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**Result jest test**

> ● BaseAnchor › triggerAnchor › should called `triggerAnchor` when clicked button
>
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
>
> Expected mock function to have been called.

If I put this way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a v-on:click="triggerAnchor()">{{ text }}</a> // Add parentheses
  </div>
</template>
```

It works, but I lost my event argument so my `event.preventDefault()` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue you can use [event modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) for v-on to implement `e.preventDefault()`:

```
<a v-on:click.stop.prevent="triggerAnchor()">{{ text }}</a>
```